# How to find an overloaded method by reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, methodinfo

This is a question associated with [another question I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436905/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-use-an-object-as-a-type-parameter/10437050). I have an overloaded method:

```
public void Add<T>(SomeType<T> some) { }

public void Add<T>(AnotherType<T> another) { }
```

How can I find each method by reflection? e.g. How can I get the `Add<T>(SomeType<T> some)` method by reflection? Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here is describing that you want the parameter to be `SomeType<T>`, where `T` is the generic type of the `Add` method.

Other than that, it's just about using standard reflection, like CastroXXL suggested in his answer.

Here's how I did it:

```
var theMethodISeek = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.Name == "Add" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
    .Where(m =>
            {
                // the generic T type
                var typeT = m.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                // SomeType<T>
                var someTypeOfT = 
                    typeof(SomeType<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { typeT });

                return m.GetParameters().First().ParameterType == someTypeOfT;
            })
    .First();
```

Comment: Sorry, another point. How to detect if a type follows a generic type's constraints?

Comment: take a peek with the debugger at `typeof(SomeType<>).GetGenericArguments().First().GetGenericParameterConstraints()` and see the `Type.IsAssignableFrom` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx I think combining them will get you what you want

Answer (score 0):

Look into the MethodInfo Members: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.methodinfo_members(v=vs.80).aspx

There are helper properties for `IsGenericMethodDefinition` and `GetParameters`. Both could help you figure out what function is what.